# curl: (6) Could not resolve host, when access subdomain

Tags: docker, docker-compose, localhost, host

Below is the URL. Below url is working for only localhost.

```
curl http://test.redzilla.localhost:3000/
```

I want to know how to get access above URL from outside the server.

I tried it by doing like below.

```
curl http://test.redzilla.11.75.65.34:3000/
```

after executing the above code below error was triggered.

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: test.redzilla.11.75.65.34
```

I just want a way to access above URL from outside the server.
There is multiple instances. each instance have a URL like above.
Instances count dynamically changed.

Comment: I'd start by just trying the numeric IP only. It may not be able resolve the name to IP. Can  you ping the URL? Do you require a proxy?

Comment: I can add proxy for this URL. Then it will working for only this URL. the first part of this URL ( "test") is dynamically changed. The instance is identified by first part for this url.  Can we create common proxy like below?.

http://*.redzilla.13.75.65.67:3000/

Comment: On the remote system add an entry in `/etc/hosts`, mapping the public ip of you machine to the domain, e.g `11.75.65.34 test.redzilla.localhost`.

Comment: I would suggest putting the curl call in a shell script where you can dynamically change the proxy based on the host you are on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need DNS to resolve the hostname. You can use a free wild card DNS service like [xip.io](http://xip.io/):

```
curl http://test.redzilla.11.75.65.34.xip.io:3000/
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I can access now for the sub domain URL. but I had another issue with NGINX location tag. If you have any idea please let me know
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57937222/502-bad-gateway-nginx-no-resolver-defined-to-resolve)